# Pack iso8583 message

Tags: bcd, ebcdic, iso8583, j8583

Ive trying to make a iso8583    pakage with j8583 library  to replace and old iso8583 program we have running ( i dont have the source code) . The packet generated its different than the packet generated by the old software. note the "f" in the old package.

the code

```
messageFactory.setAssignDate(false);

messageFactory.setUseBinaryMessages(true);

IsoMessage isoMessage = messageFactory.newMessage(0x1804);
isoMessage.setBinary(true);
isoMessage.setBinaryBitmap(true);
isoMessage.setValue(3, "000000", IsoType.NUMERIC, 6);
isoMessage.setValue(11, "000001", IsoType.NUMERIC, 6);
isoMessage.setValue(12, "151021095555", IsoType.NUMERIC, 12);
isoMessage.setValue(24, "831", IsoType.NUMERIC, 3);
isoMessage.setValue(25, "8700", IsoType.NUMERIC, 4);
isoMessage.write(outputStream, 2);
```

Old package

```
0x0000:  0a13 ad7c d6d0 0a2f 6a3b 8f1e 0800 4500  ...|.../j;....E.
0x0010:  0055 73ae 4000 4006 41de 0a00 0888 94ab  .Us.@.@.A.......
0x0020:  dde3 b88b 540c c290 a52c 976a 3432 5018  ....T....,.j42P.
0x0030:  01c9 855e 0000 002d f1f8 f0f4 2030 0180  ...^...-.....0..
0x0040:  0000 0000 f0f0 f0f0 f0f0 f1f5 f3f0 f2f9  ................
0x0050:  f1f5 f1f0 f2f0 f2f1 f1f1 f3f1 f8f3 f1f8  ................
0x0060:  f7f0 f0
```

new package

```
0x0000:  0a13 ad7c d6d0 0a2f 6a3b 8f1e 0800 4500  ...|.../j;....E.
0x0010:  0042 39a7 4000 4006 7bf8 0a00 0888 94ab  .B9.@.@.{.......
0x0020:  dde3 bcce 540c b124 15aa 1a6e e56b 5018  ....T..$...n.kP.
0x0030:  01c9 854b 0000 1804 2030 0180 0000 0000  ...K.....0......
0x0040:  0000 0000 0001 1510 2109 5555 0831 8700  ........!.UU.1..
```

Comment: I think you're missing some more `setXXX()` calls to make factory use proper settings.

Answer (score 2):

1) In old data package example you can see bytes with 'F'. It is clearly show that the encoding of data in [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) format.

2) In New package, the fields are [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) packed - The numeric fields used half of byte per digit.

For sample, from your binary data:

- Old 0x"`f1f8 f0f4`" - MTI encoded as EBCDIC
- New 0x"`1804`" - MTI encoded as BCD

Change you fields encoding mode (if your java lib supported this option).